# I try to use ets function but R can't find it

Tags: r

R just:

> Error: could not find function "ets"

`ets` is under the `forecast` package right? I can't use it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Did you run `library(forecast)` first?

Comment: i did then R: Error in ets(API, "ANN") : y should be a univariate time series

Comment: @hxnnx - That means the function was found, you just entered the wrong values.  This question is solved.  Please accept the answer below and ask a new question about the univariate time series if you are still having problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must import the library first:

```
 library(forecast)
 ?ets
```

If you get an error that R cannot find the package, you must install it:

```
 install.packages("forecast")
```

See the [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/install.packages.html)